# How to fix not attached to an activity in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

In my application I want use this library for ImagePicker : https://github.com/SimformSolutionsPvtLtd/SSImagePicker

But after add this line `private val imagePicker: ImagePicker = registerImagePicker(this)` show me Force close.

I want use this into Fragment and this fragment info **ViewPager2** .
**FragmentAdapter code :**

```
class FragmentsAdapter (fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 2
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return FragmentA()
        }
        return FragmentB()
    }
}
```

**FragmentB codes :**

```
class FragmentB : Fragment(), ImagePickerResultListener {

private val imagePicker: ImagePicker = registerImagePicker(this)

...

    private fun openImagePicker() {
        imagePicker
            .title("Images")
            .multipleSelection(false)
            .showCountInToolBar(true)
            .showFolder(true)
            .cameraIcon(true)
            .doneIcon(true)
            .allowCropping(true)
            .compressImage(true)
            .maxImageSize(2.5f)
            .extension(PickExtension.ALL)
        imagePicker.open(PickerType.GALLERY)
    }

}
```

**Error message :**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MandatoryInfoFragment{ccb6b52} (d0165abf-9555-41a8-a139-d84da8774350) not attached to an activity.
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:995)
    at com.app.imagepickerlibrary.ImagePicker$Companion.registerImagePicker(ImagePicker.kt:232)
    at com.myapp.ui.login.pages.complete.mandatory.MandatoryInfoFragment.<init>(FragmentB.kt:51)
    at com.myapp.ui.login.pages.complete.FragmentsAdapter.createFragment(FragmentsAdapter.kt:22)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `registerImagePicker` is calling `requireActivity()` to get the Context . And at the time of initialization `requireActivity()` will return `null` because the `Fragment` is not attached yet to `Activity`. See the code below.

```
 fun Fragment.registerImagePicker(callback: ImagePickerResultListener): ImagePicker {
        return ImagePicker(callback, requireActivity())
    }
```

To fix this you can move the initialization down in lifecycle Tree of Fragment after the fragment is attached for example inside `onViewCreated()` . Check fragment lifecycle.

```
class FragmentB : Fragment(), ImagePickerResultListener {

private lateinit var imagePicker: ImagePicker

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    imagePicker = registerImagePicker(this)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Fix not attached to an activity in Android

You are not passing the context correctly that's why you are getting the error.

***Add this line if you want to get the context of your activity.***

```
private val imagePicker: ImagePicker = registerImagePicker(requireActivity)
```

or

***Add this line if you want to get the context of your fragment.***

```
 private val imagePicker: ImagePicker = registerImagePicker(requireContext)
```